# Executing macro code from VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

There is a way to convert VBA code to a script, so it can be executed without running it from an EXCEL macro?

For example this code below, I want to run it without the need of opening Excel file with the macro that contains it:

```
Sub XML_FILE()

Dim filename
MsgBox "Open File"
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
If filename <> False Then
Workbooks.Open (filename)
MsgBox "Save File"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

End If

End Sub
```

What are the steps to make this and other macros to run as scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this 1. Open notepad file and paste below code:

```
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook 

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder\example.xlsm")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.Run "XML_FILE"
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

**Explanation**

1.change `objExcel.Run "Report"` with your macro function name.

Then save the file as test.vbs then run the file it will run without opening the excel file.